# Pointing One Subdomain e.g images.example.com to multiple machines Ip Addresses

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.2

How i can Point Multiple Maschines (Ip-Addresses) to one Subdomain images.example.com It serve the images from root domain. The Problem when the Storage is full at the subdomain we need more ip addresses.

How i can solve this ?

Many Thanks Sascha

Answer (score 3):

You can add multiple A records for images.example.com to the DNS zone file for example.com.

Some DNS servers will serve these in a "[round-robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_robin_DNS)" fashion so that requests are distributed fairly evenly over the IP-addresses. This is a form of [load balancing](http://zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/rr.html)

However, the HTTP servers at each address will need to be able to serve the full range of resources expected at URLs containing images.example.com. So this isn't a way of dealing with a shortage of disk space.

Maybe you should look at reverse proxying as a way of referring some requests to servers at other IP-addresses where more space is available.

Adding more disk is usually the simplest answer, in the long run, to running out of disk space. Hence SAN, NAS etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about a load-balancer or reverse-proxy (like NGINX)?

Answer (score -1):

Having A records in DNS would work like a load-balancer in this scenario.